# What parts are needed for a mono based music server?

Tags: linux, mono

I have recently installed Ubuntu Linux on my machine. This machine is on pretty much all of the time and houses my music collection. I have looked at various solutions for a central repository for music and each one is lacking in one way or another. I have done some .net programming and thought this would be an ideal project to try on MONO.

My question is this. What parts of an application are needed for streaming music around my house. I would like a web front end but other than that I'm not really sure of the parts needed to form this sort of application.

Any insight into this type of application are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to re-invent the wheel

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance

http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/3_15/settings/connectdlna.html

http://www.obsessable.com/feature/home-media-streaming-101-dlna-explained/

Since you are running linux, I suggest you try http://mediatomb.cc/